# Why I can not print Angular page with styles?

Tags: angular

There are styles in root component:

```
.div {
   width: 400px;
   height: 200px;
   background: #000;
}
```

When I click button to print out this page I get preview without styles.

How to print out with all styles of component (s)?

Comment: Provide, please, your component. Do you have div class there or its tag name? If it's tag name you shouldn't put dot before it.

Comment: Is that `div` instead of `.div`? or else did you confirm that while printing, you enabled `Background Graphics` in more settings?

Comment: Problem is each components has own isolated css files, how to make them avaialble in print out mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you link your style sheet (in `index.html`) set `media="all"` to the tag.

Or if you are importing styles in `angular.json` you can add styles for printing by this:

```
@media print {
  .class {...}
}
```

Comment: Problem is each components has own isolated css files, how to make them avaialble in print out mode?

Comment: they will combined in `styles.scss` finally. do it there and all styles will be applied.

Comment: After ng build prod? So it is not available in build mode?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do it using this print function

```
print(){
    let popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=1080,height=595');
    popupWin.document.open();
    let printContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    let printHead = document.head.innerHTML;
    popupWin.document
      .write(`<html>
         ${printHead}
        <body onload="window.print();">${printContents}</body></html>`);
    popupWin.document.close();}
```